# Server fails to properly boot/SFC will not run

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sfc

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server that has a failing RAID controller.  Unfortunately, this machine was not being backed up.  It would appear it corrupted some of the Windows drivers and the machine will not boot properly.

I booted to Restore mode from disk, as well as DVD, and tried to run `sfc /scannow offbootdir=d:\ offwindir=d:\windows`, but SFC says something along the lines of this could take several minutes.  However, no percentage is ever displayed, nor does the disk show any activity.

I booted off a Mint live CD and am currently copying the drive to another disk to be safe.

Any ideas as to how to get SFC to run?

Edit:  I would like to get this server booting, so we can install our backup agent.  This agent can then create a VM of the backup.  This machine is sharepoint testing machine for our developers.  Its not the end of the world if its gone, but it would be a large hassle.

Edit2:  After a lot of poking, I was able to finally get SFC to run and it said it successfully repaired files.  However, the machine was still not booting properly.  Im writing it off as a lost cause.

Comment: Did you try a `chkdsk d: /r` already?

Comment: did a /f , not a /r you think that will make a difference?

Comment: Did it complete successfully or did it hang mid-way like `sfc /scannow`? The `/r` option includes extra checks. It's probably worth using the official manufacturer diagnosis tool.

Comment: the chkdsk /f did complete

Comment: What was the output? Try with `/r` too once you're done backing up the data.

Comment: the backup finally finished.  Im running chkdsk /r now, looks like it will take a while

Comment: Its not looking optimistic, the scandisk /r completed, but sfc still appears not to be working.  I will let it run for a bit and see if anything happens.  But there is no disk activity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of

- `chkdsk /r`
- `dism /image:d:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions`
- deleting pending.xml from the `winsxs` folder

I was able to get SFC to run "successfully".

Unfortunately, there appears too much corruption on the drive and the OS still doesnt boot properly.  I am writing this up as a lost cause.  However, the info above might be useful to someone.